# jQuery search engine/page

Tags: jquery, match, search-engine

I need some help!!
I want to make a simple search engine that search(actually just shows) a game if you search by the name or category

```
<div id="game_thb_1">
  <div class="game_title"><span class="arcade">hamsterball</span></div>
    <div class="game_th">
      <div class="game_frame_shadow"></div>
      <div class="game_c1"><div class="game_frame"></div></div>
      <div class="game_rate_bar"></div>
      <div class="game_image"><img src="images/slideshow/game1.png" width="193" height="118"></div>
      <div class="rating_stars"><?php echo rating_bar('game1',5); ?></div>
    </div>
```

this code compose this http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/1458/capturegth.png

```
$(".searchbox_submit").click(function(){
    $('.games').hide();
    $('.contact').hide();
    $('.home').hide();
    $('.about').hide();
    $('#bookmarks').hide();
    **$('div .game_title').find(function(){$(".searchbox").val();}).show();**
    });
```

and this is the code for the search button (it doesn't work)

and I don't know how to make it like when I insert in the textbox for ex "hamsterball" and press the button to show all this code

```
<div id="game_thb_1">
    <div class="game_title"><span class="arcade">hamsterball</span></div>
    <div class="game_th">
        <div class="game_frame_shadow"></div>
        <div class="game_c1"><div class="game_frame"></div></div>
        <div class="game_rate_bar"></div>
        <div class="game_image"><img src="images/slideshow/game1.png" width="193" height="118"></div>
        <div class="rating_stars"><?php echo rating_bar('game1',5); ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont know if I can put the link to my website here (it's a demo site for school project)

Comment: Can you show the code for the whole page? (Certainly the bits between `<body>` and `</body>`, or, ideally, post a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your site so far?)

Comment: I've make it 
page :
<div class="searchbox_submit"></div>
<input type="text" class="searchbox" value="" />
<div id="game">some text for test</div>
<div class="about">some text for test1</div>
<div id="search_word"></div> 
css:
#search_word {display:none;}    
jquery script:    
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("input").keyup(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$("#search_word").text("'#" + value + "'");}).keyup();
$(".searchbox_submit").click(function() {
var word = $("#search_word").text(); 
$('div').find(word).hide();});});

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a school project, I'll just give hints:

1) You'll probably want to use the `:contains` and `:has` filters.
2) You'll need to build up the selector that includes the aforementioned filters by string concatenation (because you need to get your search value into the .
3) You probably won't need `find()` at all; you should be able to build up a single selector that will match the appropriate `<div>`.